# How to generate game pins

Tags: python

I am developing a game that requires a game PIN to join, similar to Kahoot in that regard I suppose. E.g. KA1PN2XR. I was thinking of making it 8 characters and alphanumeric, so I'm not worried about running out of combinations as there are 36^8 or about 2.8 trillion (capital letters) of them, and games will be removed once everyone has left.

However, I am wondering what is an efficient way to generate these pins? Should I use a while loop that generates one until it finds one that isn't in the database? Seems inefficient but I can't think of a much better method.

Thanks.

Comment: You could generate random pins and remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple function like this:

```
import random
w_list = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890' #characters you want in string
def generate_pin(length=8):
    tp = random.sample(w_list, length)
    pin = ''.join(tp)
    if pin not in prev_list: #list of already generated pins
       prev_list.appen(pin)
       return pin
    else:
       generate_pin()
```

Comment: So I will have to make an SQL query that retrieves all existing game pins every time a new game is created?

Comment: @JOP No need to make sql queries all time, If you are using only one application to make PINs you can save them in a local txt file for better speed, and less resource usage.
Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a loop that generates one and checks to see if it's in the database, it would probably be more efficient -- *and safer* -- to include a unique index in the database and catch the exception in the unlikely event of a collision.

For example:

SQL table:

```
create table game_pins (
    pin varchar(8) primary key,
    ...
)
```

Python:

```
import random, string


for retry in range(10):   # 10 Retries
    pin = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(8))
    try:
        (code to insert in database)
        return pin
    except (database exception for duplicate key):
        pass
    raise Exception('Too many retries generating PIN')
```

The reason this is better than a loop that checks first, then inserts, is that you're relying on the database to keep the PINs unique.

Comment: I see, thank you. How come you picked 10 retries as opposed to just a while loop? I guess it's very unlikely to reach 10 anyway given there's 10^36 combinations.

Comment: I think it's mathematically next to impossible that 10 retries could all collide. I'm thinking at that point, there's perhaps something wrong with how you're generating random numbers or your database is full of old PINs because of some kind of denial-of-service attack.

Comment: Realised I made a mistake, 36^8 not 10^36.

Answer (score 0):

if you make a random pin of 8 chars with slicing of uuid like this:

```
import uuid

print str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]
```

regarding of deleting pin after finishing game, and assuming you have 1000 users per second and each game lasts 30 minutes, probability of repeating of a pin in a second is approximately zero:
(1000*30*60)/(35^8)=7.99333749768639e-07
35 is number of alphanumeric states and 8 is number of slicing chars from uuid.
you can increase or decrease number of slicing chars based on estimating of pins generated in a second and number of users and risk of repeating.

in the worst case if you generate a uuid with 32 chars and not deleting them:
after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about 50%.

check the uniqueness of these pins is very inefficient solution for problems like these. you are deleting pins after game, and this is the heaven of random key generation algorithmes that their goals are not generating duplicate key in long run generation.

Comment: Is that any better than `session_id = "".join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(8))`? What do you think about @Ken Kinder's approach with the try/except? Seems like a good compromise.

Comment: 1.any method that generate 8 random key is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, but how about the idea of trying to enter the pin into the database with a try/except on duplicate primary key?

Comment: 2. i think ken has recommended more complex solution for problem like that with not more gaining. there is no need to 15 lines of code and touch of database for such a problem you described. uuid makes your code clean without touch of database. if you determine number of slicing chars appropriately there is no need such a solution for this problem.

Comment: you are deleting pins after game, and this is the heaven of random key generation algorithmes that their goals are not generating duplicate key in long run generation.